# Cassandra down after high traffic

Tags: configuration, cassandra, datastax, traffic, restcomm

I have a problem with cassandra when the traffic goes high... cassandra crashes
here's what i got in **system.log**

```
WARN  11:54:35 JNA link failure, one or more native method will be unavailable.
WARN  11:54:35 jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
WARN  11:54:35 JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  11:54:35 Initializing SIGAR library
INFO  11:54:35 Checked OS settings and found them configured for optimal performance.
INFO  11:54:35 Initializing system.schema_triggers
ERROR 11:54:36 Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.
java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in a recent unsafe memory access operation in compiled 
Java code at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogDescriptor.writeHeader(CommitLogDescriptor.java:87) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4] 
at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:153) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4] at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.MemoryMappedSegment.<init>(MemoryMappedSegment.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4] at
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.createSegment(CommitLogSegment.java:121) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4] 
atorg.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentManager$1.runMayThrow(CommitLogSegmentManager.java:122) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) [apache-cassandra-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

and in **debug.log**

```
DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2017-05-25 12:54:18,586 SliceQueryPager.java:92 - Querying next page of slice query; new filter: SliceQueryFilter [reversed=false, slices=[[, ]], count=5000, toGroup = 2]
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2017-05-25 12:54:18,658 SliceQueryFilter.java:307 - Read 2129 live and 27677 tombstone cells in RestCommSMSC.SLOT_MESSAGES_TABLE_2017_05_25 for key: 549031460 (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 5000 columns were requested, slices=[-]DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2017-05-25 12:54:18,808 AbstractQueryPager.java:95 - Fetched 2129 live rows
DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2017-05-25 12:54:18,808 AbstractQueryPager.java:112 - Got result (2129) smaller than page size (5000), considering pager exhausted DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2017-05-25 12:54:18,808 AbstractQueryPager.java:133 - Remaining rows to page: 2147481518
INFO  [main] 2017-05-25 12:54:34,826 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:92 - Loading settings from file:/opt/SMGS/apache-cassandra-2.2.4/conf/cassandra.yaml INFO  [main] 2017-05-25 12:54:34,923 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:135 Node configuration
[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer;
auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50;
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_user_defined_functions=false; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=all; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; num_tokens=256; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=50000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=50000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=127.0.0.1}]}]; server_encryption_options<REDACTED>;snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=5000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
DEBUG [main] 2017-05-25 12:54:34,958 DatabaseDescriptor.java:296 - Syncing log with a period of 10000
INFO  [main] 2017-05-25 12:54:34,958 DatabaseDescriptor.java:304 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2017-05-25 12:54:35,110 DatabaseDescriptor.java:409 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 1991MB INFO  [main] 2017-05-25 12:54:35,110 DatabaseDescriptor.java:413 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 1991MB
```

i don't know if this problem is related to commitLogs or not, anyways in **cassandra.yaml** i'm setting:

commitlog_sync: periodic

commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000

commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32

Comment: Is your disk is full ? Or maybe your filesystem corrupted (ie. part of the file was unreadable). You can quickly diagnose this by doing something which reads through the whole file, such as `cat file > /dev/null`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949371/java-map-nio-nfs-issue-causing-a-vm-fault-a-fault-occurred-in-a-recent-uns

Answer (score 0):

you can start you cassandra with this command:

```
cd /ASMSC02/apache-cassandra-2.0.11/
nohup bin/cassandra
```

regards,
Hafiz